# Time Cycle issue in SQL Quires.

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my rails application currently have opening and closing schedules in the application for every restaurant. Like

```
Monday 5:00 AM to 11:45 PM
Tuesday 6:00 AM to 11:00 PM
Wednesday 9:00 AM to 8:00 PM
Thursday 11:00 AM to 11:45 PM
Friday 5:00 AM to 11:45 PM
Saturday 5:00 AM to 11:45 PM
```

I have saved the above time into the database with 24hour database time format. It is working perfectly fine. as when i try to get information about the open restaurant time due to 24 hours time i am able to query the data from the database. But now my client wants that the closing time can be 2:00 AM, 2:30 AM as restaurant closes definitely after the mid night.
How it is possible to manage in the SQL Quires? How can i check for a specified period of a time restaurant is open or not?

Currently I have the following Query being executed:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*)
FROM
`sechedules`
WHERE
`sechedules`.`sechedulable_id` = 16
    AND `sechedules`.`sechedulable_type` = 'Operation'
    AND (day = 'Wednesday')
    AND (opening_time <= '21:28:23'
    and closing_time >= '02:28:23'
    and is_closed = 0);
```

I can change the cycle of the day. It can start from the 5:00 AM to 4:59 AM. But how to manage in the database comparisons I'm not getting the best possible solution.

Comment: crossing time "zones" like that is a problem. a quick/dirty hack would be to create a second shift for tuesdays, so the place opens twice that day : 12:00am -> 2:00am, then 06:00am -> 11:00pm

Comment: To be clear, is this a display issue or query issue?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary its a query issue as i want to get the restaurant which is open at a specefied time.

Comment: Maybe this? `Restaurant.where('? BETWEEN opening_time AND closing_time', Time.zone.now)`

Comment: @MrYoshiji This will not work when opening_time will be 5:00 AM and the closing_time will be 2:00 AM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you formulate your queries around start-time and duration. You could do this from your present dataset.  This query gets start time and duration from your table.

```
select weekday, 
       start, 
       stop,
       timediff(
           if (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start,stop)<0,stop+INTERVAL 24 HOUR, stop), 
           start) duration 
  from sechedules
```

As you can see, it does some monkey business to add 24 hours to the closing time if it shows up as earlier than the opening time.

Then, you can check how many records match a particular time of day like this.

```
select count(*) cnt
 where sechedulable_id = 16
   and day = 'Wednesday'
   and start <= '21:28:23'
   and '21:28:23' <= if(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,start,stop)<0,stop+INTERVAL 24 HOUR, stop)
```